# How to re-brand SpringXD?

Tags: spring-xd

Is there a way to re-brand SpringXD?

I would like to remove the default SpringXD logo appearing in the XD shell and the Admin User Interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that unless change the `banner.txt` content in the `spring-xd-dirt.jar` and `spring-xd-shell.jar`.

From other side explain, please, the reason of that: may be we ask you for the JIRA issue.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, the sprind-xd-dirt seems to be a generic distributed runtime platform with which you can build a domain specific platform. So that is why i wanted to know, whether there was a plugin based mechanism to re-brand.